# Exclude string from regular expression in C#

Tags: regex, c#-3.0

I have the next re using the c# regex class:

```
[^\r\n]+[^,"condicionesDePago"]
```

searching in the next text:

**"CREDITO 30 DIAS","condicionesDePago"**

I want to get the left part, in this case:**"CREDITO 30 DIAS"** but i only get : **"CREDITO 30**

what im missing?

Comment: Please take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a misunderstanding of what the character class is used for. It doesn't operate on words, but rather on individual characters. This part of your pattern, `[^,"condicionesDePago"]` indicates that a character should be matched provided it is **not** a comma, double quotes, or specified alphabet in that word.

You probably intended to use a look-ahead:

```
@"[^\r\n]+(?=,""condicionesDePago"")"
```

Alternately, this could be written as follows and won't match `\n` as long as `RegexOptions.Singleline` isn't specified (but it can match `\r`):

```
@".+?(?=,""condicionesDePago"")";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always expect the text to be the format above, then you might want to be explicit in your match:

```
   "(\w+ [0-9]+ \w+)"(?=,"condicionesDePago")
```

This should match Credit 30 Days (i.e. the pattern letters numbers letters - \w+ [0-9]* \w+) followed by condicionesDePago - (?=,"condicionesDePago") - called a Positive Lookahead.

I always use http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx to test my regular expressions, but I bet other people have their faves too.